# What is the newest way to set language id when run exe on Win11?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, timezone

Right now, I use `SetThreadUILanguages()` to set a thread's language to always get the timezone in English by `GetTimeZoneInformation()`.

Unfortunately, sometimes it will still return Time Zone Information in the system default language.

I think `SetThreadUILanguages()` might be too old for Windows 11, so I try to use `SetThreadPreferredUILanguages()`, but I'm not sure how to use this function.

Microsoft seems not to give a sample for this.

Comment: Have you read [User Interface Language Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/user-interface-language-management) ?

Comment: Why are you using `GetTimeZoneInformation`?  If you can elaborate about your use case, we can probably help you find a better solution.  The `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` structure is old, and even the "dynamic" version doesn't give you back the `DisplayName` - which is probably what you're looking for?  See also the note about localization of `StandardName` and `DaylightName` in the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-gettimezoneinformation#remarks).

Comment: @Matt Johnson-Pint 
My purpose is to get time zone, time zone bias and get the daylight bias if there is daylight. Do you meant TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION is so old that I should not to use it?

Comment: If you only need those values for the *current* date and time, then you can use `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION`.  But in general, you should be using `DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` for such things, as it accounts for how that data has changed over the years.  In neither case do you need to worry about the UI languages.  That only affects the localization of the names.